# Rich Text output showing extra table with defined with

Tags: visualforce, richtextarea

So im trying to output some html from salesforce and it seems to always wrap the output in

```
<table class="htmlDetailElementTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 12px; width: 929px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="">
                <div class="sfdc_richtext">
```

and inside that div is the actual text.  I even went ahead and changed the field to just a text field (instead of rich text) and in salesforce it's not showing that table but it always shows in the output.

All im doing to output is

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" Value="{!quiz.Body__c}" />
```

the biggest problem is that width that's coming back, any ideas how to remove that?

Comment: It would help immensely to see the CSS for the named table and the default table along with the divclass. I think the answer to your answers will likely be found therein. Also, since you may want to examine your RTF strings to determine if there's escaped HTML embedded therein. That also could be an issue.